# BSOD BugCheck on Multi-core system - What thread caused the crash?

Tags: kernel, server-crashes, operating-system, bsod, kernel-panic

I am aware that a Windows' system will crash with a stop error and "blue screen" for a [few common reasons](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2007/12/18/understanding-bugchecks/), some of which may be:

- A device driver or OS function that runs in kernel-mode space experiences an unhandled exception (memory access issues etc.)
- A device driver or OS function explicitly crashes the system because it detects corruption or the risk of corruption
- Faulty hardware

What I am interested in is that when examining a crash dump (in say WinDBG), the dump will always indicate the thread that caused the crash, which allows examination of the stack for that thread, providing a history of the calls that led to the bugcheck and crash. Walking this stack gives clues as to how to prevent the issue in the future (e.g. a particular driver needing updating etc.).

Knowing this, I asked myself the following question which reveals a gap in my knowledge:

1. On a multicore/processor system multiple threads will be executing simultaneously
2. Therefore surely there is the potential for two threads to simultaneously raise a bugcheck?

What happens under these circumstances?
Have I got a fundamental misunderstanding of how the OS handles multicore/processor systems in terms of concurrent execution and access to memory and hardware (IRQL and Deferred Procedure Calls (DPC) etc.)?

Thanks